# Conditional Probability and life expectancy

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

In a population of 100,000 females, 89.835% can expect to live to age 60, while 57.062% can
expect to live to age 80. Given that a woman is 60, what is the probability that she lives to
age 80?

Using conditional probability Pr(A given B) I am coming up with an answer of .57062.  I was wondering if anyone could tell me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Maybe you could _share_ with us _how_ you came up with .57062 as the answer? Perhaps consider numbers instead of percentages. How many of the 100,000 females will live to 6o years of age, and how many will have died before age 60? Now, of all these 60-year-old women, how many will live to age 80?

Comment: Did you notice that your answer, $p=0.57062$, equals the given probability $57.062\%$ that a woman will live to age 80? How did you use conditional probability? It doesn’t seem like you did, because by your calculation, the fact that a woman reached 60 doesn’t seem to have increased the probability that she will reach age 80.

Comment: pr(A given B) = Pr(A union B)/Pr(B)= (.89835 * .57062)/(.89835)

Comment: @Brian Your comment states an incorrect formula.

Comment: Ok could  you tell me whats wrong with the formula

Comment: You don't want the union, you want the intersect. $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$, you're using $P(A|B) = P(A\cup B)/P(B)$. That said, your calculation is using intersect. However you're multiplying them, which is using the intersect for independent events. Living to 60 is pretty important if you want to live to 80.

Comment: Is this a more correct statement: So 89835 women will live to age 60.  Of those 89835 women that live to 60 57062 will live to the age of 80.  So the intersection of the two events is 57062 and P(A|B)=P(A∩B)/P(B) = .57062/.89835 = .640  Am I getting closer?

Comment: Yes.  However, you should take your answer to 5 significant figures

Answer (score 2):

Let $ S $ denote the event that the woman lives up to age $ 60 $. Let $ E $ denote the event that she lives upto age $ 80 $. We need to find $ P(E | S) $.

Now, by bayes rule,

$$ P( E | S ) = \dfrac{P(S | E) \times P(E)}{P(S)} $$

Now, $ P(S|E) = 1$ since every person who lives till $ 80 $ lives till $ 60 $.

Therefore,

$$ P(E|S) = \dfrac{1.0 \times 0.57062}{0.89835} \approx 0.635186 \approx 63.51 \% $$

Answer (score 1):

Since, in this population of 100,000 women, "89.835% can expect to live to age 60, while 57.062% can expect to live to age 80", 0.89825*100000= 89835 can expect to live to age 60 and 0.57062*100000= 57062 can expect to live to age 80.  Of course, those who lived to age 80 must have been among those who lived to 60 so 57062/89835= 0.63518 or 63.518% of those who lived to be 60 can expect to live to be 80.
(adijo, I would have rounded 63.518% to 63.52% rather than 63.51% but the data was given to three decimal places rather than 2.)